# Why use the convolution matrix in Matlab as opposed to the conv() function?

Tags: matlab, matrix, convolution

I understand that if we have two vectors -say X and Y, we can calculate their convolution in Matlab using `Z = conv(X, Y)`. There's another way to do this which is, [as described on Mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/convmtx.html), through the convolution matrix:

```
n = length(Y);
Z = convmtx(X,n)*Y;
```

I have two questions:

1. Why use the convolution matrix if we can rely on `conv(X, Y)`?
2. The cited docs say that the former method is more efficient but unfortunately they don't explain why. Is it mainly due to the fact that the second method requires the computation and allocation of `length(Y)` or is there more to it (is the matrix multiplication more efficient than a convolution operation, etc.)?

Thank you!

**Edit: I contacted Mathworks.com as well and I thought I'd share their answer:**

> You can see for yourself that conv is indeed more efficient if you run this
>   code.

```
tfs = 0; tsl = 0;
Nt = 20; sh = 500;
for kj = 1:Nt
    q = randn(10000,1); h = randn(sh,1);
    tic
    fst = conv(q,h);
    tfs = tfs+toc;
    tic
    slo = convmtx(q,sh); slo = slo*h;
    tsl = tsl+toc;
end
tfs = tfs/Nt; tsl = tsl/Nt; tsl/tfs
```

> You can see that conv is faster by a factor of about 120. There are a few
>   reasons why that is the case, but the most important may be that conv is
>   (almost) a built-in compiled function, whereas convmtx is coded in the MATLAB
>   language and is interpreted when called (i.e., it is parsed, subjected to a
>   layer of type checking, etc.). Moreover, when you call convmtx you create many
>   copies of the input array, even though you really need only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convolution matrix is just the matrix that, upon multiplication, would give the same result as convolution. It's always a [Toeplitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrix.

The convolution matrix is not intended for actual **computation** of the convolution. Its application is in cases when you need to **represent** the convolution as a matrix multiplication.

As an analogy, consider the [discrete Fourier transform (DFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). As is well known, the DFT is nearly always computed with the very efficient [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm. But you can [represent the DFT as a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) if you want. You would never use that for the actual computation of the DFT; but conceptually it sometimes helps to express the DFT as matrix multiplication. For example, that allows one to view the DFT as a [change of basis in a vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis).

Comment: It might be interesting to note in this context that very often the most efficient way to compute a convolution is via the (fast) Fourier transform. :-)

Comment: @A.Donda: More efficient, yes (especially if hardware accelerated), but I believe that (depending on implementation) DFT methods can lead to greater numerical error vs. standard matrix multiplication. Correct me if I'm wrong. I can't find a good reference.

Comment: @horchler, interesting, I didn't think of that. If you find a reference, let me know.